# How to retrieve Azure blob/file/table/queue diagnosticSettings list from REST API

Tags: azure

The documentation for listing diagnosticSettings is pretty straightforward for most cases:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/diagnostic-settings/get?tabs=HTTP

Doing a GET using the following syntax will give me the top-level diagnostic settings list at the storage account level:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTIONID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCEGROUP>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<STORAGEACCOUNTNAME>/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings?api-version=2021-05-01-preview
```

However, it only returns the top-level settings. if I have blob, file, etc... specific diagnostic profiles set up, I am unsure how to retrieve a list of them from the API. I have tried appending e.g. `/blob` to the resource ID, since this is how it shows up in the portal dropdown:

[image: picture of Azure portal]

But that didn't work. I can't find an example of this anywhere.

Anyone know the proper REST URL to fetch these settings? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to retrieve Azure blob/file/table/queue diagnosticSettings list from REST API

You can use the below request if you need to get the diagnostics settings for a particular service like **`blob`**.

**Request:**

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/<your-resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageaccount name>/blobServices/default/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings?api-version=2021-05-01-preview
```

In my storage account (diagnostics settings) my blob has two diagnostics:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

you can get the similar(digonistics settings) for **`file`** ,**`queue`**,**`table`** from resource id through portal:

[image]